# Using JUnit 5 how can I test special tagged test methods

Tags: java, maven, tags, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

How can I test special tagged test methods using JUnit 5 and maven commands.
For example I have 2 test methods tagged with @unit and @integration in different classes and this classes also are in different packages under test source. And I want that maven tests only @unit tagged tests when execute mvn -Dtag=unit command or only @integration tagged tests when execute mvn -Dtag=integration command

Answer (score 1):

See section **Filtering by Tags** at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html -- you have to use `groups` and `excludedGroups` elements.

Hard-coded example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <groups>unit</groups>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```